# Loop through row and headers on separate sheets in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets, sheet 1 has the data and sheet 2 has the headers. I am trying to fill sheet 2 row 2 with either a 1 or a 0 depending if the cell value in sheet 1 matches the header in sheet 2.

I have a range in sheet 1. I can loop through this range and fill in the first cell in sheet 2 row 2 with the correct information.

The next step is where I am struggling. I need to then move to the next header in sheet 2 but again loop through the range in sheet 1.

I tried nested for loops.

```vb
Sub LoopOne()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim NxtSht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim StartCell As Range
Dim StrtCell As Range
Dim ScndCell As Range

Set sht = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set NxtSht = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set StartCell = Range("A1")
Set StrtCell = NxtSht.Range("A1")
Set ScndCell = NxtSht.Range("A2")

sht.Activate

LastCol = sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Range("A1").Select

sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastCol)).Select

For Each cell In sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastCol))
    If cell.Value = Cells(StrtCell).Value Then
        ScndCell.Value = 1
    Else
        If cell.Value <> Cells(StrtCell).Value Then GoTo escape
    End If

escape:
    NxtSht.Activate

Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: Hi. Code posted above. Excuse the roughness of it as I am still new to this and was trying to get the Coe to do what I want before tidying up. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is my quick stab at this using two nested `for each` x `in` y

```
Sub TestBed()
Dim myWB As Workbook, firstWS As Worksheet, secondWS As Worksheet, fHeaderRng As Range, sHeaderRng As Range, fOneCell As Range, sOneCell As Range
Dim fColUsed As Long, sColUsed As Long, debugStr As String

    ' Define Objects
    Set myWB = ThisWorkbook

    With myWB
       Set firstWS = .Worksheets("Sheet1")
       Set secondWS = .Worksheets("Sheet2")
    End With

    With firstWS
       fColUsed = .UsedRange.Columns.Count
       Set fHeaderRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, fColUsed))
    End With

    With secondWS
       sColUsed = .UsedRange.Columns.Count
       Set sHeaderRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, sColUsed))
    End With

    For Each sOneCell In sHeaderRng
        For Each fOneCell In fHeaderRng
            If fOneCell.Value = sOneCell.Value Then
                debugStr = "Match || First Addr: " & fOneCell.Address & " || Second Addr: " & sOneCell.Address
                Debug.Print debugStr
                sOneCell.Offset(1, 0) = 1 ' 1 = Match
                GoTo Next_sOneCell
            Else
                debugStr = "No Match || First Addr: " & fOneCell.Address & " || Second Addr: " & sOneCell.Address
                Debug.Print debugStr
                sOneCell.Offset(1, 0) = 0 ' 0 = No Match
            End If
        Next fOneCell
Next_sOneCell:
    Next sOneCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I will give it a go and see if it works. Thanks again

Comment: Tested this earlier and it works a treat. Thank you for you help. I now need to stop to the next row in sheet 1 and run through the loop again. This I will try and work out from the code you have provided. Thanks again.

Comment: Add a `fRowsUsed` variable and use this for defining the `fHeaderRng`.  Assuming the 2nd sheet has only two rows then this should work well.

Comment: @Bezum. Do you mind if I pick your brain regarding this code I am still trying to write?

Comment: Hi @TheRunner83 sorry I haven't been active on this site lately.  If you still have questions I'd be happy to assist.